# How can I prevent apt update from checking specific components?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I sometimes come across repositories that include many components, or at least I think that's what they're called. An example of this, is the repository including Insomnia. When I run apt update after adding this repository, apt update goes through a lot of different components, most of which are not even hits.

Is there any way to prevent apt update from including these components? I've included a shortened version of my apt update output below.

```
$ sudo apt update                              
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease   
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease                  
Ign:14 https://download.konghq.com/insomnia-ubuntu default InRelease           
Ign:16 https://download.konghq.com/insomnia-ubuntu default Release
Ign:17 https://download.konghq.com/insomnia-ubuntu default/all all Packages
Ign:18 https://download.konghq.com/insomnia-ubuntu default/all amd64 Packages
Ign:19 https://download.konghq.com/insomnia-ubuntu default/all Translation-en_US
Ign:20 https://download.konghq.com/insomnia-ubuntu default/all Translation-en
Ign:21 https://download.konghq.com/insomnia-ubuntu default/all amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this; the best way in this case, to limit the scope of the changes, is to specify that specific repositories should only have their package indexes updated.

To set that up, edit the corresponding `sources.list` entry (either in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`) so that it starts with

```
deb [target=Packages]
```

Once that’s done, `apt` will no longer retrieve any other index from that repository.